# PHP Cron Manager / Scheduler

Tags: cron

We work on projects in which we have several cron jobs. One that run every 30 mins , one that runs every midnight, one that runs at 2:00 PM etc. Now instead of setting individual cron jobs every time, is there some sort of PHP cron manager class, which I can schedule to run say every 1 minute and using that manager I can fire other crons/scripts at specific time or intervals. We are planning of developing one like this, but I was looking for existing options before we start, but couldn't find any. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try PHP Cron Daemon. It is better than a lot of others I have looked at because it uses forking. Without forking (or some other kind of process management), your 30 mins scripts would have to sit waiting for your daily scripts to complete before starting...

Edit: link no longer available